# Why are there single quotations even though I am using double quotation marks?

Tags: python

I am solving Fizz Buzz on leetcode and I am facing this issue of getting single quotes instead of double quotes.
Code:

````
class Solution:
def fizzBuzz(self, n: int) -> List[str]:
    answer = []
    for number in range (1, n+1):
        if number % 5 == 0 and number % 3 == 0:
            answer.append("FizzBuzz")
        elif number % 5 == 0:
            answer.append("Buzz")
        elif number % 3 == 0:
            answer.append("Fizz")
        else:
            answer.append(f"{number}")
    print(answer, end='')```
````

Output:

```
Runtime: 59 ms
Your input
3
stdout
['1', '2', 'Fizz']
Output
[]
Expected
["1","2","Fizz"]
```

Comment: in python there is no distinction between single quote and double quote, both represent string

Comment: It's utterly ridiculous, but if you want what is expected, try: `print(f'''["{'","'.join(answer)}"]''')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to print it you have to return the output on coding platform

change this

```py
print(answer, end='')
```

to this

```py
return answer
```

interpretation

```
stdout << what is output on stdout/console/command line
['1', '2', 'Fizz'] << printed value of array
Output << what is returned
[] << Empty array
Expected << expected return
["1","2","Fizz"] <<< expected to return this array
```